# Recovering file from bad synchronization

Tags: ubuntu-one, restore

I am using Ubuntu One file synchronization on two computers. Both systems were disconnected from the Ubuntu One service for some days and changes were made to the same file on both systems. On one system the changes were insignificant, something like the file being touched or something similar. On the other system there were significant changes. Both of the systems reconnected to the file synchronization service at about the same time and Ubuntu One overwrote the file with all of the changes. There were no conflict files in this case. I would have hoped for and expected a conflict.

It seems like there should be something I can do about this, that the service wouldn't just overwrite files without some way of restoring old versions. Revision history is supposed to be a strength of couchdb. Can I use this strength to restore my files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Versioning is a strength of CouchDB, but CouchDB is not used by file synchronization.

However, conflicts are handled gracefully, albeit not entirely user friendly yet. In the same directory as your original file, you will find files called filename.u1conflict*, like mydocument.odf.u1conflict and mydocument.odf.u1conflict2, etc. Those are the original conflict files, so you can just rename and use them as before.

Comment: From what I've seen in the past this should be the right answer. I didn't see any of the conflict files in my case. This was part of the problem, no evidence of the recognition of any conflict. I was hoping that there might be some couchdb style versioning and I could go back to a previous revision.

Comment: There is. When there is a conflict, the old version is kept as a .u1conflict<number> file.

Comment: In this case I didn't get conflict files. There wasn't a history of previous versions like you get with couchdb, where you can access previous revisions all the way back to a point where compaction would have removed them. I guess that I wasn't clear enough originally when I said "I would have hoped for and expected a conflict." That meant I expected these conflict files that you have mentioned. I'd seen them before in other conflicts. Since there were none, I hoped that couchdb was tracking the changes so maybe I could somehow get access to a deeper history. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it says "CouchDB is not used by file synchronization"